# Recommendation engine using google-prediction-api?

Tags: recommendation-engine, google-prediction

In google's prediction api page, it says we can use it for recommendation of webpages / products...

Can someone please show me how, for example:

I have 500,000 members purchased history

I have 2,000,000 products in 200 different categories

I have user-X just signup, asked him 15 'like' / 'dislike' product questions (user's taste)

Now, i want to suggest/recommend user-X with a list(e.g. 500) of products which he most likely willing to purchase

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/hello_world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not specifically tied to Google API fow whatever reason, explore using Mahout. This is a basic use case for the Mahout Recommendation mining.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/itembased-collaborative-filtering.html

Answer (score 2):

The Google Prediction API, as currently implemented, is great for classifying data into a discrete set of categories, however, as noted in the documentation:

> Avoid having a high ratio of categories to training data in categorical models.
>   Try to have at least a few dozen examples for each category, minimum.
>   For really good predictions, a few hundred examples per category is
>   recommended.

The Prediction API's classification doesn't work well when the ratio of categories to examples is high and in the example you sketched the relationship is one-to-one because you are trying to find the user whose liked product list is most similar to the user of interest (to find a set of promising products to recommend). In this model, each user is a unique category.